# Get value from One function and pass it to another

Tags: reactjs

I have a function called on onDatabaseSelect which retrieves values of a database as shown here in the console with the given key property name and value of Object_name: "".

[image]

```
  const onDatabaseSelect = (e, value) => setDatabase(value)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("set database", database)
  }, [database])
```

it is being called here:

```
   <div style={{marginRight: '210px', width: '100%'}}>
              <AutoCompleteSingle
                name='Database'
                label='Database'
                options={autoComplete.databasesAutoComplete}
                onChange={autoComplete.onDatabaseAutoCompleteFieldUpdate}
                onSelect={onDatabaseSelect}
                uniqueIdentifier={1}
              />
            </div>
```

I need to push the value of the object_name to the return value of new state

```
  const [productionDatabaseData, setProductionDatabaseData] = useState([])

const addToProduction = ({ target }, { id, databases }) => {

    setProductionDatabaseData((previousState) => {

      let newState = [...previousState]
      if (target.checked) {
        newState = [
          ...newState,
         {  unit_test_id: id, databases }
        ]
      } else {
        const i = newState.findIndex(({ unit_test_id }) => unit_test_id === id)
        if (i !== -1) newState.splice(i, 1)
      }
      return newState
    })
  }
```

Expected output:

[image]

So the object_name should be pushed into the databases array if checked and if unchecked it should be removed.

so if I were to check the value of onDatabaseSelect which would be "stg_successfactors"

the new value should look like this:

```
databaseArr = {
unit_test_id: 166.
databases["iagdcanonprod.auiag.corp/project_entrust_australia_dev", stg_successfactors.ext_gpload_reusable_e24181c8_f3ed_11ea_836b_fa163e5628e8", "]
}
```

Update Error:
[image]

The databases state lives in another component...I was wondering if I passed props correctly?

```
  const addToProduction = ({ target }, { id, databases: mappedDatabases }) => {
    setProductionDatabaseData((previousState) => {
      let newState = [...previousState];
      if (target.checked) {
        newState = [
          ...newState,
          {
            unit_test_id: id,
            databases: [
              ...mappedDatabases,
              ...props.databases.map(({ object_name }) => object_name)
            ]
          }
        ];
      } else {
        const i = newState.findIndex(({ unit_test_id }) => unit_test_id === id);
        if (i !== -1) newState.splice(i, 1);
      }
      return newState;
    });
  };
```

Comment: Hello again. What is the relationship between `onDatabaseSelect` callback invocation, `database` state update, and `addToProduction`? Are you simply wanting to append the `database` state to `productionDatabaseData` state when it [database] is updated, like in another effect?

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for answering again! Yes I  am simply wanting to append the database state to productionDatabaseData. Specifically the object_name. The onDatabaseSelect has the values of the database which I want to pass and append to the productionDatabaseData state as you said :). Thanks for helping out your fellow juniors! haha.

Comment: So if you've a response object, an array of database objects, you want to append each `object_name` property values to the existing `productionDatabaseData` array? Can you provide an example expected output from some sample response data?

Comment: Yes that is correct, this has been updated for you @DrewReese

Comment: Oh, wait, so the `database` state is *just* an array of "selected" databases from `AutoCompleteSingle`? And you want `addToProduction`, when invoked, to add or remove the database names from `productionDatabaseData.databases` depending on the checked value of the event object? Is `addToProduction` even relevant, I thought that was a handler somewhere else? Is the checkbox value persisted in state anywhere?

Comment: Yeah also correct, addToProduction is relevant as I want to be able to append that array of 'selected' databases from the autocompletesingle to the end of productionDatabaseData databases array. If I am making sense.

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to understand. If the checkbox is checked then you add a new object with a `databases` array (with `object_name` values appended), but if the checkbox is ***not*** checked you remove that entry entirely, so there's no `databases` array to remove elements of. Am I overthinking this entirely?

Comment: yes, spot on. That is correct, sorry if I made it unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map `databases` state array to an array of the `object_name` values

```
databases.map(({ object_name }) => object_name)
```

And spread both the `databases` array from the mapped UI and object name array into a *new* array. You'll have to rename the destructured `databases` function parameter to avoid the name clash with component state.

```
const addToProduction = ({ target }, { id, databases: mappedDatabases }) => {
  setProductionDatabaseData((previousState) => {
    let newState = [...previousState];
    if (target.checked) {
      newState = [
        ...newState,
        {
          unit_test_id: id,
          databases: [
            ...mappedDatabases,
            ...databases.map(({ object_name }) => object_name)
          ]
        }
      ];
    } else {
      const i = newState.findIndex(({ unit_test_id }) => unit_test_id === id);
      if (i !== -1) newState.splice(i, 1);
    }
    return newState;
  });
};
```

Comment: You sir are an angel sent from heaven. Thank you!

Comment: how would I go abouts renaming the de structured databases function parameter?

Comment: @bloombloom Are you referring to this: `{ databases: mappedDatabases }`?

Comment: @bloombloom Ok, what I did in my solution was renaming a destructured property. In `{ id, databases: mappedDatabases }` I destructured both `id` and `databases`, but renamed `databases` to `mappedDatabases`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names